# Count(*) retornando null

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tenho esta query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_IND_COLUMNS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE')
     AND COLUMN_NAME IN (UPPER('ANO'),UPPER('MES'),UPPER('DIA'),UPPER('HORA'))
     GROUP BY INDEX_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) = 4;
```

Como não existem registros, ele deveria retornar 0 mas não retorna nada, como fazer para que retorne 0 caso não haja ocorrências.

Comment: Você explicitamente está selecionando apenas os que possuem `count` igual a 4, mas espera que fique 0 no resultado? Seria como pegar somente as meias brancas do guarda-roupa e estranhar que não há nenhuma vermelha no meio.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso? Eu preciso pra testar um if neste resultado.

Comment: Primeiro você precisa descrever exatamente o que precisa fazer. Se precisa de resultados que tenham valor diferente de 4, basta remover tal condição. Aliás, qual o sentido de fazer `UPPER('TABLE')`, `UPPER('ANO')`, etc? Todas as strings são estão em caixa alta, então por que utilizar a função `upper`? Não deveria estar junto com o valor que é variável?

Comment: @Douglas Mas não é questão de elegância, é de coerência. Poderia "resolver" com coalesce, mas como você quer que resulte em zero se você explicitamente diz que só quer quando a contagem for igual a 4?

Answer (score 0):

O having funciona como uma espécie de where para os elementos do group, nesse caso não existe nenhum registro com contagem igual a 4 respeitando o agrupamento.

uma forma de fazer isso seria utilizando subconsulta:

```
select count(*) 
from (
    SELECT COUNT(*) contagem FROM USER_IND_COLUMNS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE')
     AND COLUMN_NAME IN (UPPER('ANO'),UPPER('MES'),UPPER('DIA'),UPPER('HORA'))
     GROUP BY INDEX_NAME 
) where contagem = 4;
```

Comment: Não consigo nem transformar o resultado em 0 nessa condição?

Answer (score 0):

Se partirmos do princípio que a sua tabela tem uma chave primária (ou coluna com valores únicos), pode fazer algo do género:

```
SELECT      ISNULL(X.CONTADOR, 0) AS CONTADOR, UIC.*
FROM        USER_IND_COLUMNS UIC
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      CODIGO
                        ,   COUNT(1) AS CONTADOR
                FROM        USER_IND_COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE')
                        AND COLUMN_NAME IN (UPPER('ANO'), UPPER('MES'), UPPER('DIA'), UPPER('HORA'))
                GROUP BY    INDEX_NAME 
                HAVING      COUNT(1) = 4
            ) X ON X.CODIGO = UIC.CODIGO
```

Utilizei a coluna **`CODIGO`** como chave da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Tire o `having` que está removendo o retorno e coloque a condição no próprio *select*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 4 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) END
FROM USER_IND_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE')
  AND COLUMN_NAME IN (UPPER('ANO'),UPPER('MES'),UPPER('DIA'),UPPER('HORA'))
GROUP BY INDEX_NAME;
```

Comment: adicionei o `distinct` pra evitar que retorne _mil_ resultados..

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_IND_COLUMNS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE')
     AND COLUMN_NAME IN (UPPER('ANO'),UPPER('MES'),UPPER('DIA'),UPPER('HORA'))
     GROUP BY INDEX_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) = 4);0)
```